# Connecting to remote filesystem in Window Explorer as another user

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-explorer

I'm trying to connect to a file server from PowerShell. The script should ask me for my server-administrator password and then should open an Explorer window which shows the content of the shared folder.

My problem is, that I'll get no Explorer window open at all or I'll get an error which says: Permission denied.

This is my script so far:

```
$SrvAdmin = "<Domain>\sadmin" + $env:USERNAME

function Login {
    $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Zugriff auf Laufwerk I" -UserName $SrvAdmin
    if (-not ($cred -is "System.Management.Automation.PsCredential")) {
        return
    }
    $mmcPath = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"

    Start-Process explorer.exe -FilePath "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" -ArgumentList '\\sv123\d$' -Credential $cred
}

while ($b=1) {
    $a = 0
    try {
        Login
    } catch {
        $a = 1
    }
    if ($a -ne 1) {
        break;
        $b = 2
    }
}
```

I also tried `Invoke-Item` and to open a second PowerShell, or a batch file as server administrator, where I tried to open the path in Explorer.

Comment: Have you thought of mapping the drive?  `New-PSDrive`

Comment: IIRC an Explorer process always launches as the current user.

Comment: You could try `start explorer C:\ -Verb runas` or `start explorer C:\ -Credential domain\user` - but I have a niggling feeling that Bill is correct. Edit: nvm - I didn't read your post properly... >.>

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this isn't working since Windows Vista anymore because an Explorer process opens always as the current user.

Thanks for your answers guys :)